# Where is the top of the overflow tube on a toto flush valve?

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing a fluidmaster fill valve. The directions make a big point of making sure the critical line is an inch above the top of the overflow tube, for code compliance. However, on the toto (dual) flush valve I can't find the overflow tube. I guess it's internal to the device? Looks like this one:

[image]

Also, is there some obvious test I could do to see if the fill valve is too low vs. the overflow tube? How does it fail if it's wrong?